# osmconvert - errors while merging maps in Windows 10 - unknown file format, could not open input file: .osm.pbf

Tags: openstreetmap, osmconvert

I've donwloaded the following maps:

```
andorra-latest.osm.pbf       https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/andorra-latest.osm.pbf
azores-latest.osm.pbf        https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/azores-latest.osm.pbf
cyprus-latest.osm.pbf        https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/cyprus-latest.osm.pbf
```

And I am using [osmconvert](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Windows) to merge maps. I read [this answer](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/48843/merging-two-or-more-geographical-areas-to-import-two-or-more-osm-files-in-nominatim)  to merge maps. So my command of merging the above maps looks like this:

```
.\osmconvert andorra-latest.osm.pbf --out-o5m | .\osmconvert - azores-latest.osm.pbf | .\osmconvert - cyprus-latest.osm.pbf -o=all.osm.pbf
```

However, the osmconvert shows the following errors after running the above command:

```
osmconvert Error: unknown file format: standard input
osmconvert Error: could not open input file: .osm.pbf
```

[image]

However, the merging perfectly works in **Windows 7** and **Windows Server 2016** Standard

Does anybody know how to solve this error?

Comment: Duplicate post: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/71934/osmconvert-errors-while-merging-maps-in-windows-10-unknown-file-format-could-not-open-input-file-osmpbf

Comment: @mmd yeah, it is my question. I thought these are tow different sites. So I believe morepeople will see this question to get an answer.

Comment: Posting the same question on multiple sites at the same time without linking to each other is considered bad etiquette. Please don't do it, it wastes everyones time.

Comment: @mmd If I will find answer, then I will paste answer in both places to be available an all commuinties.